# In GraphQL, how to "aggregate" properties

Tags: graphql, apollo

Excuse the vague code, I can't really copy/paste. :)

I have type in GraphQL like this:

```
type Thing {
    toBe: Boolean
    orNot: Boolean
}
```

I'm trying to create a new property on this type that is an... aggregate of those two. Basically return a new value based upon those values. The code would be like:

```
if (this.toBe && !this.orNot) { return "To be!"; }
if (!this.toBe && !this.orNot) { return "OrNot!"; }
```

Does this make sense? So it would return something like:

```
Thing1 {
    toBe: true;
    orNot: false;
    newProp: "To be!"
}
```

Comment: you can define two one for input `input` with two fields only and another for the `type` output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can easily create aggregated fields in your graphql `Object types` by handling your required logic in that aggregated field `resolver`. While creating object types, you have instance of that object, and therefore, you can easily create **aggregated fields** which are not present in your domain models using object's data and ***this is one of the beauty of graphql***. Note that this can differ on each implementation of GraphQL libraries. Following is the example for such use case in `JavaScript` and `Scala`.

> Example in Graphql.js:

```
var FooType = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: 'Foo',
  fields: {
    toBe: { type: GraphQLBoolean},
    orNot: { type: GraphQLBoolean},
    newProp: { type: GraphQLString,
    resolve(obj) {
        if (obj.toBe && !obj.orNot) { return "To be!"; }
        else { return "OrNot!"; }
    }
  }
});
```

> Example in Sangria-graphql:

```
ObjectType(
    "Foo",
    "graphql object type for foo",
    fields[Unit, Foo](
      Field("toBe",BooleanType,resolve = _.value.name),
      Field("orNot",BooleanType,resolve = _.value.path),
      Field("newProp",StringType,resolve = c => {
          if (c.value.toBe && !c.value.orNot) "To be!" else "OrNot!"
      })
    )
  )
```

Answer (score -1):

The various GraphQL server library implementations all have ways to provide *resolver functions* that can provide the value for a field.  You'd have to include it in your schema and write the code for it, but this is a reasonable thing to do and the code you quote is a good starting point.

In Apollo in particular, you [pass a map of resolvers](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/essentials/data.html#resolver-map) that get passed as a `resolvers:` option to the `ApolloServer` constructor.  If a field doesn't have a resolver it will default to returning the relevant field from the native JavaScript object.  So you can write

```js
const resolvers = {
  Thing: {
    newProp: (parent) => {
      if (parent.toBe && !parent.orNot) { return "To be!"; }
      if (!parent.toBe && !parent.orNot) { return "OrNot!"; }
      return "That is the question";
    }
  }
};
```